# Image wrong orientation in html5 preview

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose my image is not upright (I open it in window browser and the image it not upright), but when I upload it to some server (such as gmail, stackoverflow). The image becomes upright.

I asked this question is that I am writing a preview logic with html5 and javascript. The image that I talk about show what exactly I see in window browser. Just wondering if the server did some trick to adjust the orientation?

Image shown in windows:

[image]

Image that directly upload to stack overflow:

[image]

Comment: What does "open it in window browser" mean?

Comment: I uploaded the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you are talking about an image you generate or manipulate client-side using a `canvas` element that is then rendered back into an `img` tag.  Correct?

Server-side, the orientation can be determined by looking at the image's EXIF orientation flag.  It IS possible to examine this flag client-side using a library like [jQuery fileExif](https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-fileExif).

Answer (score 2):

If you use a script like [ImageInfo](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/imageinfo/) you can fetch EXIF data (if the image has it). If it hasn't you practically can't know why it happened. Might be some "fake" displaying on the computer you are working on. Some image managers might keep duplicates of an originally rotated image.

The EXIF property `Orientation` might tell you if the image is changed, based on it's dimensions compared to it's orientation.

Answer (score 0):

On Server Side:
You can use a tool like Graphics Magic to auto-orient the image correctly: http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html

```
gm.exe -convert -auto-orient MyImage.jpg MyImageCorrectOrientation.jpg
```